# Save several ggplots to files

Tags: r, string, ggplot2, concatenation

I want to save a changing set of ggplot is different files. To do this I use a for-loop looking something like this:

```
save = c("plot1","plot2")
for (i in 1:length(save)){
  ggsave(cat(save[i],"\n"), file="i.pdf")
}
```

"plot1" and "plot2" are working ggplots (=names of the plot objects). Because I got the following error:

```
Error in ggsave(cat(save[i], "\n"), file = "i.pdf") : 
  plot should be a ggplot2 plot
```

I tried the cat-function. It returns the same error with or without the function. If I enter the "plot" directly it works...

What am I doing wrong?

(Edited the example so there is more than one plot)

Comment: `c("plot")` is a single-element character vector. You're passing a string with a newline into the first parameter of `ggsave` which is expecting a filename.

Comment: But how would I do this if there are more than one elements in this vetor E.g. save = c("plot1","plot2")

Comment: Can you show some more code? Are those the names of the plot objects?

Comment: Yes, they are the names of the plot objects...sorry if that was unclear!

Comment: `cat` always returns NULL and only has a side-effect of printing to the console. It is completely inappropriate to use it as an argument in a function.

Comment: Thats strange. If I execute cat it just returns the first element of the vector without " `> cat(save[1], "\n")
> plot1 `

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to specify the argument plot in ggsave :

```
ggsave(plot = plot, file = "save.pdf")
```

If you have several ggplot you need to save them in a list first.

```
plotlist = list()
plotlist[[1]] = plot1
plotlist[[2]] = plot2
```

etc. Or any other way. Once you end up with the list you can loop on it :

```
for(i in 1:2){
  ggsave(plot = plot[[i]], file = paste("file",i,".pdf",sep=""))
}
```

That will save you the plots in file1 file2 etc.

Comment: This works for me. Thanks. One additional thing though...How can I name the files according to the list elements? As is plot1.pdf, plot2.pdf...

Comment: The above code will save as file1.pdf, file2.pdf etc. if you change the line to : `ggsave(plot = plot[[i]], file = paste("plot",i,".pdf",sep=""))` it will do the saving as plot1.pdf plot2.pdf etc. Try to run `i=1` and then `paste("plot",i,".pdf",sep=""))`  you will understand that paste only creates a proper name file using your index i

Comment: so I can't get the string from the list? Lets say we are not talking about plot1 and plot2 but abc and def. How would the names of the files be abc.pdf and def.pdf?

Comment: You can definitely use the name from the list by doing : `ggsave(plot = plot[[i]], file = paste(names(plotlist)[i],".pdf",sep=""))` Is that what your were looking for ?

Comment: I am doing something wrong. E.g. `names(plotlist)[1]` just returns `NULL`

Comment: By default a list does not have any names. when you create the list you can add them : `plotlist[[1]] = plot1` then you can add the name `names(plotlist)[1] = "nameplot1"` you can replace nameplot1 by whatever you want repeat that for all the item in the list (in the above case 2). You can also define the name in one shot after having filled the list with the plot via : `names(plotlist) = c("name1", "name2")`. Running the for loop should now do what you want ;)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `get` to get the object based on the name:

```
library(ggplot2)

plot_1 <- qplot(mpg, wt, data = mtcars)
plot_2 <- qplot(mpg, wt, data = mtcars, geom="path")
plot_3 <- qplot(mpg, data = mtcars, geom = "dotplot")

plot_names <- c("plot_1", "plot_2", "plot_3")

for (i in 1:length(plot_names)) {
  ggsave(filename=sprintf("%s.pdf", plot_names[i]), 
         plot=get(plot_names[i]))
}
```

But, you are really better off storing your plots in a `list` and iterating over the list elements:

```
plots <- list(length=3)
plots[[1]] <- qplot(mpg, wt, data = mtcars)
plots[[2]] <- qplot(mpg, wt, data = mtcars, geom="path")
plots[[3]] <- qplot(mpg, data = mtcars, geom = "dotplot")

for (i in 1:length(plots)) {
  ggsave(filename=sprintf("plot%d.pdf", i), 
         plot=plots[[i]])
}
```

You can store them named if you want to use the plot name as the output or add a list element for the name.

Answer (score 0):

```
# List of plots
PlotList <- list(Object$plots)


# PDF
pdf("ManyPlots.pdf")
PlotList
dev.off()
```