# Pass name of list iteration during map to ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
df1 <- mtcars
df2 <- mtcars

combined_mtcars <- list(first_df = df1, second_df = df2)

# make the plots
map(.x = combined_mtcars, .f = function(i) {
  ggplot(i, aes(x = hp, y = mpg, group = cyl)) +
    geom_line()
})
```

This generates two charts, one for each df in combined_mtcars.

I would like to add a title to each chart where the title is the name of the iteration, for "first_df" for the first plot and "second_df" for the second one.

Tried:

```
imap(.x = combined_mtcars, .f = function(i) {
  ggplot(i, aes(x = hp, y = mpg, group = cyl)) +
    geom_line() +
    ggtitle(.y)
})
```

Which gave an error "Error in .f(.x[[i]], .y[[i]], ...) : unused argument (.y[[i]])
"

How can I pass the iteration name to ggplot?

Comment: You need `imap(combined_mtcars, ~ ggplot(.x, aes(x = hp, y = mpg, group = cyl)) + geom_line() + ggtitle(.y))`. If you are using anonymous function call, then use `function(i, .y) or `function(i, j)` i.e. `imap(.x = combined_mtcars, .f = function(i, j) {
  ggplot(i, aes(x = hp, y = mpg, group = cyl)) +
    geom_line() +
    ggtitle(j)
})`

Comment: Yep, that did it, thank you once again

Comment: For bonus, do you know how I can save? Tried adding ```ggsave(filename = .y, path = "/plots", device = "png"))``` which gave error Saving 6.62 x 5.57 in image
Error in grid.newpage() : 
  could not open file '/plots/add_email_subscribers'

Comment: You may check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26495400/save-several-ggplots-to-files)